# Add email validation to existing php file

Tags: php, validation, email

how can I add email validation for existing php file?

PHP file:

```
    <?php
if (count($_POST)) {

    $email   = 'receivermail';
    $subject = 'our subject';
    $message = 'messageOK';
    $error   = 'messageNOTOK';
    $charset = 'utf-8';
    $head    = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=$charset\r\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
    $body    = '';
    foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++) {
                $body .= "$name=" . (get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($value[$i]) : $value[$i]) . "\r\n";
            }
        } else
            $body .= "$name=" . (get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($value) : $value) . "\r\n";
    }
    echo mail($email, "=?$charset?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=", $body, $head) ? $message : $error;
}
?>
```

Form in another html file:

```
<form method="post" action="name_of_the.php" name="ourform" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the filter_var function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

`filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Comment: You really should expand on this "answer" as it really is no better than a comment.